# Phonegap 2.7 - IOS MapKit

Tags: cordova

I have working for a few days on getting a workable version of The IOS Mapkit plugin for Phonegap 2.7.

https://github.com/jcesarmobile/my-phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/MapKitPlugin
(credits to jcesarmobile)

This guy claims it works on version 2.6, but i haven't tested it yet on 2.6. I have achieved similar coding to this one, but i ran out of ideas. I feel it's a simple step towards making this work on 2.7.

Can someone help me with this, please?

PS: There is also a warning in Xcode, but i don't know if this is affecting it

> .../Plugins/Mapkit/MapKit.m:100:19: Instance method
>   '-objectFromJSONString' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: I'll check it this afternoon, next time create a "new issue" on github, it's easier for me to know if somebody have problems

Answer (score 0):

This version it's supposed to work with phoengap 2.7, haven't tested

[imhotep MapKit plugin](https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit/tree/master/src/ios)

Edit: mine wasn't working, and this isn't working either, but I changes some things and sent them a pull request that is working